# How to detect browser viewport change in size?

Tags: viewport

Please, how can I detect changes in the viewport? The following code works well when viewed in desktop mode:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer_bottom_content">    
            <div class="footer_bottom_areas">
                <div class="footer_bottom_areasz">
                    <img class="footer_logo" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="footer_logo">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-social-medias">
                    <a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_terms">
                    <a href="#"> Terms of Use</a>
                    <a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a>
                    <a href="#"> Cookies </a>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_copyright">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-copyright"> 2023 </i>
                    
                </div> 
            </div>           
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer_bottom_content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 882px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer_bottom_content.scrolledz {
  background: linear-gradient(-225deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 25%, rgba(0, 36, 66, 0.979) 53%);
  opacity: 0.99;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  const headerChangek = document.querySelector(".footer_bottom_content");
  if (window.scrollY < 3296) {
  headerChangek.classList.add("scrolledz");
  } 
  else {
  headerChangek.classList.remove("scrolledz");
  } 
  })
```

In mobile mode, the background color will only change when the page is scrolled to a considerable amount of increments.

Although a duplicate of this will work when the scrollY pixel is twice the desired value, but the code required will be too, hence the need. Thanks.

Comment: Any tip will be appreciated. Thanks